# Can't add Products back to Products model after deleting it from Cart, Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cart

In an E commerce  Rails App I'm building products that is deleted from the ShoppingCart are not added back to the production model after deletion.

When I add Products to the Cart the App is using this controller below to decrease the number of products from the Product model( see the create method)

`controllers/product_item_controller.rb`

```
class ProductItemsController < ApplicationController

include CurrentCart

before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
before_action :set_product_item, only: [:show, :destroy]

def create

    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_item = @cart.add_product(@product.id)
    if @product_item.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice:'Product added to Cart'
        product = Product.find params[:product_id]
        product.update_columns(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity - 1)
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def set_product_item
    @product_item = ProductItem.find(params[:id])
end

def product_item_params
    params.require(:product_item).permit(:product_id)
end

end
```

That is woking fine.

But when I delete the Cart it gets deleted but the products are not added to the products model. And I also get this messages : `Invalid Cart`

this is the `carts_controller.rb`

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

def new
    @cart = Cart.new
end

def show
     @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
 @random_no = rand(5)
 @random_image = @images[@random_no]

end


def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    product = Product.find params[:product_id]
    product.update_columns(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity + 1)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
end

def remove
    cart = session['cart']
    item = cart['items'].find { |item| item['product_id'] == params[:id] }

    product = Product.find(item['product_id'])
    product.update_columns(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity + 1)

    if item
        cart['items'].delete item
    end
  redirect_to cart_path
end


private

def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

def cart_params
    params[:cart]
end

def invalid_cart
    logger_error = 'You are trying to access invalid cart'
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Invalid Cart'
end
end
```

I Can't see what is wrong with this code and why the products are not added to the `product.rb` after being deleted from the Cart.

Am I missing something here? Could someone advise me here?

Below are other relevant models and controllers

`products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def show

  end

def search

@product = Product.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC")
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @product.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct

end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd, :price_isl, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query)
end
end
```

`Cart.rb`model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1

    else
        current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item


end

def total_price_usd
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price_usd}
end

def total_price_isl
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price_isl}
end
end
```

`product.rb`model

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :label

has_many :product_item, :dependent => :destroy

#before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item



    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true


 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

 #def ensure_not_product_item
 #  if product_item.empty?
 #      return true
 #  else
 #      errors.add(:base, 'You have Product Items')
 #      return false
 #  end

 #end

 def self.search(query)

 where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%") 
end
end
```

Comment: You have `has_many :product_item` in Product while it should be `has_many :product_items`. You also want to be more careful when it comes to pluralization of variable names as well - calling a variable that contains a collection `@product` and not `@products` will trip you or someone else up.

Comment: Also doing `@product.map{|x| x.id }` is not a good idea. Just pass the collection/proxy `@product` instead and rails will either extract an array of ids or create a subselect.

Comment: Ok thanks, note taken, but I'm still not able to add products to the product.rb after deletion from the Cart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rescuing from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
```

But you're probably rescuing inappropriately... from the `Product.find...` in the destroy method.  I'm not sure why you would expect the product_id to be in params.

Your code...

```
def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    product = Product.find params[:product_id]
    product.update_columns(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity + 1)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
end
```

A better alternative might be...

```
def destroy
    if @card.id == session[:cart_id]
      @cart.product_items each do |product_item|
        product_item.product.update_columns(stock_quantity: product_item.product.stock_quantity + 1)
      end
      @cart.destroy
    end
end
```

However this might better be done as a `before_destroy` action for product_item model, so that destroying a product_item will automatically increment the stock total.

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution, it is what I needed at the moment. Max answer is though very informative and great.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to give a line by line solution as there are quite a few points about this application that not quite right and require a bit of rethinking. Lets look at how a shopping cart commonly is done.

### The models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products, through: :orders
  def current_order
    orders.find_or_create_by(status: :open)
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:in_cart, :processing, :shipped]
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
end

# The join model between a Order and Product
# The name line item comes from the lines on a order form.
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
end
```

The naming here is not a mistake or sloppy copy pasting. A cart is only a concept in web app which exists as a "user aid" in creating an order.

The join between a Order and Product is commonly called a line-item. Note that we use `has_many though:` so that we can query:

```
User.find(1).order
Product.find(1).orders
Order.find(1).products
```

### The Controllers

When building something as complicated as a checkout you will want to pay attention to the Single Responsibility Principle and KISS. Having many classes is not a bad thing. Having huge tangled controllers that do far too much is.

So for example create a controller that has adding and removing items from the cart as its sole responsibility.

```
# routes.rb
resource :cart
  resources :line_items, 
      only: [:create, :destroy, :update] do

    collection do
      delete :clear
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/line_items.rb
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_cart
  before_action :set_item

  rescue_from Orders::NotOpenError, -> { redirect_to @order, error: 'Order is locked and cannot be edited' }
  
  # Add an item to cart
  # POST /cart/line_items
  def create
    @cart.product_items.create(create_params)
    # ...
  end

  # Remove an item from cart
  # DESTROY /cart/line_items/:id
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    if @item.destroyed?
      redirect_to cart_path, success: 'Item removed.'
    else
      redirect_to cart_path, alert: 'Could not remove item.'
    end 
  end

  # Remove all items from cart
  # DESTROY /cart/line_items
  def clear
    @order.line_items.destroy_all
    if @order.items.count.zero?
      redirect_to cart_path, success: 'All items destroyed'
    else
      redirect_to cart_path, alert: 'Could not remove all items.'
    end
  end

  # Update a line in the order
  # PATCH /cart/line_items/:id
  def update
    @line_item.update(update_params)
  end

  private
    def set_order
      @order = current_user.current_order
      # Ensure that order is not processed in some way
      raise Orders::NotOpenError unless @order.open?
    end

    def set_line_item
      @line_item = @order.line_items.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity)
    end

    def update_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity)
    end
end
```

Notice how nicely the path for route each clearly tells us what it does and how we can write a description of the controller in a single line without using the word `and`.

In addition to this you will want a `ProductsController`, `CartController`, `OrderController`, `PaymentsController` etc. each of should do a single job - and do it well.

### Don't do it all in your controllers!

When we add a line item to a order the available stock of the product should of course decrease. This is a clear cut example of business logic.

In MVC business logic belongs in the model layer.

A user adding a item to the cart should only create a reservation. The actual inventory of a product should only be altered when the order is processed or ships:

```
# No callbacks needed!
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
  
  def reservations
    line_items.joins(:order)
              .where
                .not(line_items: {
                  order: Order.statuses[:shipped]
                })
              .sum(:quantity)
  end

  def availibity
    stock - reservations
  end
end
```

Comment: I would encourage you to look at something how something like Spree is coded. There is a quite a bit to creating an actual checkout and helps to learn from the masters.

Comment: Also this code is a general example demonstrating concepts - it is not tested and probably has a fair share of errors.

Comment: This is some really good answer, I'll sure use it as a reference in future projects.... but Steve's answer accomplish what I needed at the moment. Yours is though more informative and has deepen my understanding about building E commerce apps, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You've got

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :destroy]
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
```

As soon as the `CartsController#destroy` method is invoked the private method `set_cart` is called. What it tries to do is to initialize an instance variable `@cart = Cart.find(params[:id])`.

The first line of your `#destroy` method is `@cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]`. Isn't the `@cart = Cart.find(params[:id])` a problem here? What is the value of `params[:id]`? I guess it's  not the same as `session[:cart_id]` and might probably be a `nil` or some Intreger value by which the DB cannot find a Cart record, hence the error.

**Edit 1:**

The same applies to the `product = Product.find params[:product_id]` as Steve mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819549/cant-add-products-back-to-products-model-after-deleting-it-from-cart-ruby-on-r#answer-39819798).

Max posted a very informative [report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819549/cant-add-products-back-to-products-model-after-deleting-it-from-cart-ruby-on-r#answer-39820977) on how it should be done properly. If you have the time stick to his answer and try to redesign your app in accordance to his suggestion.